# Tests not triggered from feature level if @env tags are added at feature level

Tags: karate

For our karate API tests feature file, we have added @env tag on the feature file level as applicable to tests. But when i am clicking on Run option at the feature file level ( using karatelabs VSCode plugin), tests are not triggered.

Using the maven command / runner / running individual scenario works fine. Only issue i am seeing is from the feature file level.

```
@regression @env=test,devlop

Feature: Test Scenario

Background: Login
  * url URL
  * print ("Login call executed")
  
@sanity
Scenario:  Get Info
    Given path basepath
    When method GET
    Then status 400
    
@sanity
Scenario:  POST info
    Given path basepath
    When method POST
    Then status 400
```

I am also seeing a similar issue when multiple examples are added for a scenario outline with different @env tags.

I can create a separate question for that. But would like to understand if the behaviour mentioned is by design and if the issues are linked?

```
Scenario Outline:  Test
    Given path <path>
    When method Get 
    Then status 200

@env=develop
Examples:
    | path |
    | developpath |

@env=test
Examples:
    | path |
    | testpath |
```

Comment: this may require an improvement to the plugin: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-vscode-extension/issues/12 - you should be able to work around by using the command-line

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas for quick response. I am using command line / runner as a workaround. it seems it would be same root cause for scenario outline issue. Would you be able to confirm it or does it need a separate question?

Added the examples of scenario outline issue in the original description.
In this case, when i click on the run from scenario level in above examples, those are not executed as well but command line works fine.

Comment: yes, this requires an improvement to  the plugin

Comment: note that now the Karate extension has native support for VS Code launch configurations: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-vscode-extension#launch-configurations

Comment: Thanks, @PeterThomas for confirming back. We are still using the free plugin version, so will continue using maven command.